# How to implement least cost path through matrix in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell

Hello I have a particular question I cant find any resources on for Haskell. I'm looking to create a function that takes a mmatrix in as a parameter and returns an array for haskell. something like:

```
returnPossiblePaths :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
```

The condition though, is that I return the the array with the 'least cost path' or the path that has the lowest sum. So if I have the matrix:

```
[6 9 3
 2 5 7]
```

I want to iterate from the head to the tail, add the numbers up in that path and return the array with the smallest sum. e.g:

```
6 -> 9 -> 3 -> 7 = 25
6 -> 9 -> 5 -> 7 = 27
6 -> 2 -> 5 -> 7 = 20
6 -> 2 -> 5 -> 9 -> 3 -> 7 = 32
```

So here my result array would be: [6, 2, 5, 7]. I need help on how to go about doing this. I have no idea how I would go about iterating from head to tail in different 'paths' without going through all the elements. My general plan was to get all the paths into arrays, map sum to al of them then compare the results and return the array with the smallest sum. So I would first get all the arrays (paths) from the matrix then apply this function to them:

```
addm::[Int]->Int
addm (x:xs) = sum(x:xs)
```

store those values in a variable, compare them then return the lowest one. I know haskell has amazing functions that make this way easier and I was wondering if I could get help on how to go about doing this. Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The problem is not very clearly worded. You are trying to implement a least/most cost path through a 2d matrix algorithm. This can be done with Dijkstra. Implementing it in Haskell then is the next issue.

Comment: sorry, what should I do to word it better, I can edit it for better understanding.

Comment: I don't think it's particularly poorly worded, aside from the fact that you never mention you're treating the matrix's values as the "cost to move here from any adjacent cell", with adjacency implied by having a nearby index. The problem I see is that the question is very broad. You need to pick an algorithm first, and then you need to work on implementing it in Haskell before you can have a problem specific enough to get Haskell help on.